# How to repair a broken DVI port on my monitor?

Tags: repair

I bought an LG452T-TF monitor about two years ago and the DVI port seems to be busted. The problems first started about a week ago. After waking my computer up from sleep the monitor only showed grey static or flickering. I initially tried different cabling to rule out a bad cable with no success. I gave up frustrated and the tried again the next day and it worked perfectly with the original cables. Then a few days later it died again and it's been about a week with no luck trying different DVI cabels. However, it does work via the VGA input. Since it died, resurrected, died again and given that the VGA port works I've concluded it's probably a loose or broken DVI input port on the monitor. Since LG doesn't seem to want to honor their three year warranty (no word from them) and I don't really want a new monitor (most new affordable 24" monitors are all 16/9 instead of 16/10) I'd like to try to fix it myself, but I'd like some advice before I begin as I've never repaired TV or a monitor before.

I'm hopping someone can pass on some advice about how to fix it. Specifically I'd like to know how difficult it would be, what tools I'd need, and if there are any general how to guides you could point me to.

Thanks!!

Comment: Honestly, the warranty is the best shot in my opinion unless they flat out refuse. Or, if DVI isn't that important, most graphics cards support legacy VGA through a DVI to VGA converter.

Comment: @Thomas O: so it'd be tough repair? :(

Comment: @evan, It might not be difficult for someone who is experienced, but you might damage more trying to repair it. Just get one of these (http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A4837&rt=nc&_nkw=dvi+to+vga&_sticky=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&_sop=15&_sc=1), stick it on the back of the graphics card and use the VGA interface, unless you have some reason not to. Most graphics cards still support it.

Comment: @evan When you return something like that the manufactures will usually run some very quick diagnostics in order to tell what subsystem has an issue and then will usually just replace that whole subsystem and then sell it as a refurb.

Comment: @Thomas O: I actually had a vga-dvi converter laying around and have already done that for the moment but I don't think (no actually proof of this, just opinion) that I'm getting the same quality I was over dvi which is what led me hopping it wouldn't be to hard to just repair the monitor myself. I appreciate your advice and Keyllenjb's though, I'll only attempt the repair if they definitively deny the warranty :). Thanks!

Comment: @evan, You'll get a bit more noise, but generally, using well shielded VGA cables (not cheap, thin ones) you'll notice little difference.

Answer (score 2):

Good money says it's a loose connector - connectors are the first place to look when nearly anything goes wrong with an electronic system (second is the power supply).  If a couple of pins have come loose things can certainly go south.

The way to fix these things is to open up the case (read that as: Step 1 - void your warranty), identify the connector and give it a once over with a magnifying light to see if there are any cracked solder joints.  These are likely fixable with a soldering iron (if you can get everything suitably positioned and braced).  No recommendations from me on what solder or temperature to use exactly but you'll want thin solder, preferably lead-free I think and if your soldering iron supports it start with a low temperature and work your way up until it's easy to work with.

Alternately, if you have a heat gun or other hot-air rework you can aim it at the connector, heat it up a but and remove the heat to let all of the connections melt and reapply themselves.  I'm not sure if I would do that if it's entirely surface-mount though as it may float slightly off the pads if all of the connections get loose at once.